# Correlating meetings in Outlook calendar on different computers

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-calendar

If you send a meeting request to someone using Outlook, no user or custom MAPI properties will go into the meeting created the attendee's Outlook calendar.

I am looking for a way to correlate meetings that belong together across multiple attendee's computer.

I have found that the "Conversation ID" or the first 44 characters of the "Conversation Index" property are the same across all attendees computer, ONLY if all the attendees are on the same MS Exchange server. This does not work for different exchange servers or local computer only calendars.

Is there any reliable way that I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appointment id (`AppointmentItem.GlobalAppointmentID`) will be the same for all instances of the appointment.